# Should I change our application code so our protractor tests can use by model or binding over id?

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

fairly new to the world of Angular and Protractor, updating myself using various style guides such as the official protractor one - https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide

Within it, it tells us:

> Prefer protractor-specific locators such as by.model and by.binding.

Currently, we're using css locators, mostly by id or class and they seem fine.  However, I'm curious if we should be changing things over to by model or by binding.  Is there a performance benefit in doing so?  The explanation for why you should use them over other locators seems to be because they're short and that's about it.

I cannot find any information out there in terms of performance benefits thus far.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not recommand the selection `by.model` or `by.binding`. For a simple reason.
If you want later to use an another e2e test framework as [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), it will be easier to migrate with simple `class`, `id`, `attribute`, `tag` selectors.

Comment: +1 for not changing, out of many reasons, the main one is because there is no clear benefits, but requires to put some effort

Comment: yes I guess the main question is why are they recommending by model or binding?  I cannot find anything on any tangible benefit

Comment: Keep in mind that it's only effective for AngularJS and not angular. But Why they recommend that whith angularJs ? Simple. Your code will eventually have more change with the class, ids or tags than for the name of the model or binding.  So it's less error prone I guess